# Clicking on NotifyIcon flips between 3 states (not 2)

Tags: vb.net, forms, hide, show

I know this can be done... since I've seen other vb.net executables do it.

When I hit the program's NotifyIcon in the SystemTray... I thought I would only need to toggle between:

```
1>  Show my form
2>  Hide my form
```

But I really need to flip between all 3:

```
1>  Show my form
2>  Hide my form
3>  If my form is visible... but behind other programs... 
    just bring it to the front.
```

I can only seem to get #1 and #2 to work.  How would I do all 3?
(I do *NOT* want to make my form permanently "always on top".)

```
' Flip between #1 and #2
If (Me.Visible) Then
   Me.Hide()
Else
   Me.Show()
   Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal  ' In case user minimized it earlier
   Me.Activate()   ' Active and give focus (brings to front, also)
End If
```

I can't really check for "is my form active"... because hitting the NotifyIcon causes that very mouse-click to *MAKE* all forms "not active".

Edit:  I'm NOT really worried about other windows like "the start bar" or "always on top" windows... appearing over mine.  (Since they will ALWAYS be over mine.)

I guess I really just need to detect:  "Me.Show is true... and Me.Active is false".  (But my NotifiIcon-click will ALWAYS make my form non-active... so how can I check for true/false???)

I really want it to just work the way windows does:  Clicking on anything in the task-bar does NOT just make it "open" (if closed)... and "close" (if opened).  It always does 1 more thing:

> > > > > Detect if it's already open, but behind other windows, so do NOT close it... but rather... make the window appear.

Checks for 3 different things.   Does 3 different things.  (Never just 2)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get some use out of the [GetNextWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.  You can use it to see which windows are over top of your window.  It won't be easy, but you can probably make it work.

To see which windows are above yours, use

```
Const GW_HWNDNEXT as Integer = 2 'Returns a handle to the window below the given window.
Const GW_HWNDPREV as Integer = 3 'Returns a handle to the window above the given window.

Declare Function GetNextWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindow" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wFlag As Integer) As Integer 

hWndPrev = GetWindow(Me.Handle, GW_HWNDPREV)
```

Bear in mind that even when your window is the active window, there will probably still be some windows above yours, like the start bar and AlwaysOnTop windows.  You'll need to detect these based on their class or position/size (whether they overlap your window).

Best of luck!

Comment: I'm not really worried about "always on top" windows being over mine.  (Since they will ALWAYS be over mine.)   Excluding those... how can a user put windows over mine... if mine is still active?    Wouldn't mine HAVE TO BE deactive?  How can I detect that... and make it active?  (Remember, my click on the notifyIcon will make my form... and *ALL* forms deactive.  So how can I still detect mine used to be the active one?)  I guess I need to detect:  My window is NOT set to Me.Hide ... but it's also NOT active.  (But remember... my notifyIcon-click will ALWAYS make it "not active".)

Comment: If you loop through the windows that are above (previous), this may help.  You can use spy++ (spyxx.exe) to see what I'm talking about.  This will help you detect if some other window is above yours.  Form.Activate will probably work to activate your window... if not, p/invoke the SetForegroundWindow api.

Comment: Wow.  I was hoping there would be no need for spyxx.exe or any API calls at all.... just to do this very simple thing:  Detect if my form was the active form... when I click on my NotifyIcon.  (But the click itself, prevents me from ever doing that.... since the CLICK makes the form non-active.)

Comment: What about the form.deactivate event? If you record the time at deactivate and then when notifyicon raises it's event, see if less than a second elapsed.

Comment: I tried that.  What if the user does some work in other window for 2-1000 seconds?  My form was deactivated "long ago".  But it's still "open and behind".